# Cannot get selected value from dropdown within the bind function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

my pseudo-code below

```
$("#oneElement").bind(
    "change",
    {
        field:$("#theDropDownList").find("option:selected").text()
    },
    theFunction
);
```

when `$("#oneElement")` changes, it then calls `theFunction (event) {}` and I would expect to find the selected value from `$("#theDropDownList")` in `event.data.field`.

But `field` is never updated from when I load the webpage even after changing `$("#oneElement")` multiple times.

**EDIT : ** `theFunction` looks like

```
function theFunction(event) {
    console.log(event.data.field);
    //do whatever
}
```

All help welcome !

Comment: Can you show us what `theFunction` is? We cannot tell if you're doing it correctly in there.

Comment: `bind` is deprecated in jQuery, so it's sort of a bit odd to see it, even for pseduo-code.  (Plus, given it has a different function to JavaScript `bind`which makes things worse)

Comment: the data is probably calculated in binding time not when the event is caught. I'll elaborate shortly

Comment: @Tibrogargan  how would you achieve the same result without using `bind` ?

Comment: This is occurring because `eventData` is passed to the function as is, it's not evaluated at when the event is fired, so you're going to get the values as there were when `bind` was called

Comment: You would use use `on` ... and probably just get rid of the `eventData` argument altogether, since it doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: @Tibrogargan yes ok but what if I need to pass arguments to the function that reside on the webpage ?

Comment: The function can access anything on the webpage already, you would only need to use `eventData` if there's data that is going to go out of scope or is inaccessible at the time the event is fired

Comment: fair enough. i'll modify accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the object value is calculated during the binding once and passed to the function when the event is triggered. if you want to have the value in real time you shouldn't pass it as data while binding. get it from within the function because it executes after the event is triggered.

```js
$("#oneElement").bind(
    "change",
    {
        field:$("#theDropDownList").find("option:selected").text()
    },
    function(event){
     //bind time
     console.log(event.data.field);
      //run time
      console.log($("#theDropDownList").find("option:selected").text());
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="theDropDownList">
  <option value="1">text 1</option>
  <option value="3">text 2</option>
  <option value="3">text 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="oneElement"/>
```

Comment: Ended up going that way and changing the `bind` function (which is apparently deprecated) to `on`.

Comment: it is deprecated in v3. you may need to read this article for more details http://elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `bind` which is deprecated, I would recommend you to use `on`.

You can do it this way:

```
$("#oneElement").on("change", theFunction);

function theFunction() {
  var someValue = $("#theDropDownList").find("option:selected").text();
}
```